# simple php pagination or css pagination with php/mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am trying to built a simple php pagination ( a sort of ).
or  to be more specific css pagination with php/mysql.

**Accessing and storing the values from db**

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id[]=$row["id"];
        $name[]=$row["name"];
        $url[]=$row["url"];
        //echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["name"]. " " . $row["url"]. "<br>";
    }
```

**Displaying them**

```
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="#">«</a></li>
        <?php 
         $i=1;
        for ($x = 0; $x < count($id); $x++) { ?>
        <li>
         <a href=<?php echo "$url[$x]"; ?> target="iframe1"
 title="<?php echo "$name[$x]"; ?>"><?php echo "$i";?></a> 

         </li>
        <?php   $i++;}   ?>


        <li><a href="#">»</a></li>
      </ul>
```

**Once any number shown above is clicked required url is displayed inside iframe1**

```
 <div align="center">
    <iframe name="iframe1" src="http://www.w3schools.com"
 frameborder='0'  height='1000'   width='1000' align="center"></iframe>
    </div>
```

when I click any number it display the url inside the iframe "iframe1" .

**Question:**

How do i display first and NEXT {NOT LAST} record in

```
  <li><a href="#">«</a></li>  [First]
  <li><a href="#">»</a></li>  [Next]
```

I am looking for a very small code to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

The first link is pretty easy:

```
<a href=<?php echo "$url[0]"; ?> target="iframe1" 
    title="<?php echo $name[0]"; ?>"><<</a>
```

For next link It would kind of depend on how your urls are set out. If the `$url` values are just a name and your url is domain.com/blog?page=page1 where page1 is the value from `$url` then we get use `$_GET['page']` to grab the current page. Then using:

```
$next = array_search($_GET['page'], $url);
```

will give us the number in the order of the current page so the next page will simply be `$url[$next + 1]`

EDIT:

OK if its a url that changes in domain part then the $_GET wont work. You could grab the current url using `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` and then use the same technique as above to find its position in the array of urls.

Comment: one url in each colum. www.example.com .. then next url www.example2.com and so on. any sugestions for this

Comment: Edited my answer with what i would try based on it being different domains.